# IntelliJ 14 use AspectJ inpath

Tags: intellij-idea, aspectj, intellij-14

I need to weave a few jars in addition to my source. In Eclipse / Ant the way to do this is using the inpath option. Ant and Eclipse provide significant support for adding jars this way. Is there anything similar for IntelliJ (I am using 14)?

I've used the AspectJ Weaver plugin, but it does not allow me to put advice on methods that are part of Jars.

Edit: I used `-inpath` as extra command line paramaters, however I get compilation errors from that indicating that it could not figure out the base class of any of the classes in the inpath jars.

Edit2: For now I am not using intellij's make, instead I am building the output using Ant. It is not ideal but it works, and without much speed loss.

Edit3:
jars used for -inpath compilation: spring-tx-3.2.11, spring-orm-3.2.11, spring-binding-2.3.1

From debug logging of intellij's build, this is pretty much for every class in that jars

```
 [Xlint:cantFindType]' @(no source information available)
/Users/dlikhten/Developer/workspaces/x/src/x-web/web/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-binding-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:0::0 
2014-12-10 13:28:52,992 [  23440]  DEBUG - ng.aspectj.build.AjBuilderBase - error: 'can't determine superclass of missing type javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException
when weaving type org.springframework.binding.expression.el.MapAdaptableELResolver
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As much as I love IntelliJ IDEA for the most part, I have to admit that I switch to Eclipse whenever dealing with AspectJ because IDEA's AspectJ support is not state of the art. Okay, AspectJ is an Eclipse project, so good support there is to be expected, but anyway.

The only way I found to use the *inpath* on external libraries is actually customising the *Ajc* command line for your project and just add an `-inpath my/external/lib.jar`:

[image: Java compiler settings for Ajc]

---

**Update:**

Here is my little demo project with an aspect and a driver application using *Apache Commons Compress 1.9*. Just make sure to change the path to your sample ZIP file in order to get it running:

```java
public aspect DemoAspect {
    before() : execution(public * *(..)) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

```java
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveException;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveStreamFactory;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ArchiveException {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        ArchiveInputStream input = new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("c:\\Users\\Alexander\\Downloads\\rudi.zip")
            )
        );
        ArchiveEntry entry;
        while ((entry = input.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

**Console output without *commons-compress-1.9.jar* on *inpath*:**

As you can see, the aspect works. It intercepts the main method's execution. Then the main method prints "Hello world!" and the 3 file names from my sample zip.

```
execution(void Main.main(String[]))
Hello world!
index.cgi
upload.cgi
cmd.cgi
```

**Console output with *commons-compress-1.9.jar* on *inpath*:**

Now put the external JAR on the *inpath* like in the screenshot. **Use the full path, please!**  We now expect to see a lot of public method executions from *Commons Compress* intercepted and logged by the aspect as well. And really, after "Build" -> "Rebuild project" the output changes to:

```
execution(void Main.main(String[]))
Hello world!
execution(ArchiveInputStream org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveStreamFactory.createArchiveInputStream(InputStream))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes())
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes(long))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes())
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes(long))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes())
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes(long))
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.matches(byte[], int))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes())
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes(long))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes())
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes(long))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes())
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes(long))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes(long))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes(long))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes(long))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes(long))
execution(ZipEncoding org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipEncodingHelper.getZipEncoding(String))
execution(ArchiveEntry org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.getNextEntry())
execution(ZipArchiveEntry org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.getNextZipEntry())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getPlatform())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(GeneralPurposeBit org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.parse(byte[], int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.useDataDescriptor(boolean))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.useUTF8ForNames(boolean))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.useStrongEncryption(boolean))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.useEncryption(boolean))
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.usesUTF8ForNames())
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.usesDataDescriptor())
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setGeneralPurposeBit(GeneralPurposeBit))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setMethod(int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getBytes(long))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipUtil.dosToJavaTime(long))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int))
execution(String org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.FallbackZipEncoding.decode(byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getPlatform())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setExtra(byte[]))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.register(Class))
execution(ZipShort org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.AsiExtraField.getHeaderId())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.register(Class))
execution(ZipShort org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.X5455_ExtendedTimestamp.getHeaderId())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.register(Class))
execution(ZipShort org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.X7875_NewUnix.getHeaderId())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.register(Class))
execution(ZipShort org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.JarMarker.getHeaderId())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.register(Class))
execution(ZipShort org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.UnicodePathExtraField.getHeaderId())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.register(Class))
execution(ZipShort org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.UnicodeCommentExtraField.getHeaderId())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.register(Class))
execution(ZipShort org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.Zip64ExtendedInformationExtraField.getHeaderId())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(ZipExtraField[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.parse(byte[], boolean, ExtraFieldUtils.UnparseableExtraField))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setExtraFields(ZipExtraField[]))
execution(ZipExtraField[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getExtraFields(boolean))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.mergeLocalFileDataData(ZipExtraField[]))
execution(ZipExtraField org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getExtraField(ZipShort))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(String org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getName())
execution(ZipExtraField org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getExtraField(ZipShort))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setSize(long))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getMethod())
execution(ZipMethod[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.values())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getMethod())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(String org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getName())
index.cgi
execution(ArchiveEntry org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.getNextEntry())
execution(ZipArchiveEntry org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.getNextZipEntry())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getPlatform())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(GeneralPurposeBit org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.parse(byte[], int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.useDataDescriptor(boolean))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.useUTF8ForNames(boolean))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.useStrongEncryption(boolean))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.useEncryption(boolean))
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.usesUTF8ForNames())
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.usesDataDescriptor())
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setGeneralPurposeBit(GeneralPurposeBit))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setMethod(int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipUtil.dosToJavaTime(long))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int))
execution(String org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.FallbackZipEncoding.decode(byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getPlatform())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setExtra(byte[]))
execution(ZipExtraField[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.parse(byte[], boolean, ExtraFieldUtils.UnparseableExtraField))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setExtraFields(ZipExtraField[]))
execution(ZipExtraField[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getExtraFields(boolean))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.mergeLocalFileDataData(ZipExtraField[]))
execution(ZipExtraField org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getExtraField(ZipShort))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(String org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getName())
execution(ZipExtraField org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getExtraField(ZipShort))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setSize(long))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getMethod())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getMethod())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(String org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getName())
upload.cgi
execution(ArchiveEntry org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.getNextEntry())
execution(ZipArchiveEntry org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.getNextZipEntry())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getPlatform())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(GeneralPurposeBit org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.parse(byte[], int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.useDataDescriptor(boolean))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.useUTF8ForNames(boolean))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.useStrongEncryption(boolean))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.useEncryption(boolean))
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.usesUTF8ForNames())
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.GeneralPurposeBit.usesDataDescriptor())
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setGeneralPurposeBit(GeneralPurposeBit))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setMethod(int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipUtil.dosToJavaTime(long))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int))
execution(String org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.FallbackZipEncoding.decode(byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getPlatform())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setExtra(byte[]))
execution(ZipExtraField[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.parse(byte[], boolean, ExtraFieldUtils.UnparseableExtraField))
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setExtraFields(ZipExtraField[]))
execution(ZipExtraField[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getExtraFields(boolean))
execution(byte[] org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ExtraFieldUtils.mergeLocalFileDataData(ZipExtraField[]))
execution(ZipExtraField org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getExtraField(ZipShort))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(String org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getName())
execution(ZipExtraField org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getExtraField(ZipShort))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.hashCode())
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.setSize(long))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getMethod())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getMethod())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipMethod.getCode())
execution(String org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry.getName())
cmd.cgi
execution(ArchiveEntry org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.getNextEntry())
execution(ZipArchiveEntry org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.getNextZipEntry())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[]))
execution(int org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipShort.getValue(byte[], int))
execution(boolean org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.equals(Object))
execution(long org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipLong.getValue())
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately I keep getting compilation errors indicating that it cannot figure out the base class for any of the classes in any of the inpath jars.

Comment: Then maybe those base classes are missing. If you share your project with me (e.g. via GitHub), I can probably help you. BTW, a Maven build with well-defined dependency management would enable you to build via command line, IntelliJ and Eclipse, you would no longer be dependent on IntelliJ. But this is just an additional hint, I am sure we can sort this out anyway. I just need more information. You have 1,700+ reputation points, so I guess you have enough experience to know that generic error descriptions are not very helpful when it comes to reproducing a problem. Show me the code!

Comment: We have a build running perfectly well in Ant and Eclipse. I unfortunately cannot share the project with you as it is a private repository which I don't have permission (legally) to share. It appears that "post-compile weaving" option in the modules made a difference (strange). But it still does not appear to be weaving the .jar file and thus the aspect is not getting invoked. I did confirm in Eclipse that the code path I am testing is accurate, so IntelliJ compiler is the only x-factor.

Comment: Distill a minimal version into a stand-alone project with dummy classes exposing the problem then. Maybe that way you even notice by yourself what is happening. Shave off more an more parts unrelated to the problem until it no longer occurs, the go one step back. But either way: If you cannot help us reproduce the problem, we cannot help you solve it. Do not keep us guessing - StackOverflow is not a quiz show, it is about source code. I have tested my solution, and it works nicely.

Comment: One more thing: What do you mean by "IntelliJ compiler"? IDEA uses javac or ajc, depending on your settings.

Comment: I am using AJC, sorry.

Comment: So does Eclipse, so does Ant. Your problem is not the compiler, it is your configuration. I cannot speculate and help you with something you are unwilling to share.

Comment: I edited my original post. For now I am switching to using ant for building. I thank you for even attempting. I'll probably delete this post as it may end up being deemed unhelpful. I have no doubt the compiler works perfectly fine. I'll experiment with a simplified version of my project and reach out if I find an isolated version of my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Please do not delete it. I put time in answering it and creating a sample project and screenshot. My answer is basically correct because it answers the initial question of how to use *inpath* in IDEA. This could be of general interest. Only later we found out that your problem is a little bit different from what you thought.

Comment: I have just updated the answer by some sample code from my demo project plus console output proving that it actually works as described above.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a major difference, the jars I use are spring-tx, spring-binding, spring-orm.

Comment: I did the effort of making a mini-project. It appears that IntelliJ has no issue with the -inpath being the spring tx/binding jars. I assume I made a very similar configuration to my main project, but it would appear that something is not quite the same. Thank you for your answer. url: https://github.com/dlikhten/intellij-test-aspectj-inpath

Answer (score 0):

The problem faced was two-fold + 1 bonus:

- IntelliJ 14.0.0 - 14.0.2 seems to have a compiler bug. When you modify the aspectj compilation options (like command line paramaters) in OSX it appears to ignore the changes until the *next* build. So basically change = needs 2x builds before it takes effect. Caused my troubleshooting to be off.
- The compilation error I got from the spring jar was because I don't have all dependencies. The reason I didn't see it in ant is because someone used the -Xlint:ignore option, which ignores those errors and weaves any files it can, which is fine since those classes are not used in our code at all.
- It appears the 14.0.2's incremental compiler for aspectj ignores the command line arguments for aspectj. Wonderful.